# How to find whether the same value exist in all the rows of the given array list in angular

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, typescript

I have list of values in a array list as below

```
"data": {
  "input": [
      { "weight": 'KG', "Amt": 40 },
      { "weight": 'KG', "Amt": 20.25 },
      { "weight": 'KG', "Amt": 10.30 }
    ]
  }
```

How to find the above list has same weight for all three records in typescript
here the weight is not fixed. it will be dynamic and different for each time we get the above list some time

```
"data": {
            "input": [
                {"weight":'', "Amt": 40},
                {"weight":'KG',"Amt": 20.25},
                {"weight":'Gram',"Amt": 10.30}
                {"weight":'KG',"Amt": 10.30}
            ]
        }
```

I need to get true if the above list has same weight for all the records

Comment: What all possible units do you have? And what does this means `"weight":''`?

Comment: Can you describe your solution with an example? Same weight for all three records, what does that mean?

Comment: @Arcteezy, It's a dynamic value from backend. We can't define it

Comment: @Nitheesh if all three records has same weight as KG or empty or Gram, I should returns as true

Comment: @Nishanth So just the weight field needs to be same? And doesn't depend at all on Amt?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `array.every`. Here is an example:

```js
const input = [
  {
    "weight": '',
    "Amt": 40
  }, {
    "weight": 'KG',
    "Amt": 20.25
  }, {
    "weight": 'Gram',
    "Amt": 10.30
  }, {
    "weight": 'KG',
    "Amt": 10.30
  }
]

const sample = input[0].weight;
const result = input.every((item) => item.weight === 'KG');
console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't know all the different weight types.

```
const bla = [{"weight":'gram', "Amt": 40},
            {"weight":'gram',"Amt": 20.25},
            {"weight":' ',"Amt": 10.30}
        ];

const findDiff = (arr) => {
    const aWeight = arr[0].weight;
    for(let i=1;i<arr.length;i++) {
        if(arr[i].weight!== aWeight) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
console.log(findDiff(bla));
```

Answer (score 0):

You Loop twice and compair the elements one by one:

```
flag: true;
array.forEach(element1 => {
    array.forEach(element2 => {
        if(element1.weight !=== element2.weight ) {
            flag= false;
        }
    });
});
```